# Invalid type assertion by pointer to array

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and confused about the type assertion. Why can't the following snippet be compiled? what could be the problem by the type assertion in this example?

```
arr := new([5]int)
arr1, ok := arr.(*[5]int)
```

Comment: Remember that Go is statically typed, therefore the type of `arr` is always known and there would be no reason to try and assert a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type assertion is only for interface.

> A type assertion provides access to an **interface** value's underlying concrete value.

source https://go.dev/tour/methods/15

example:

```golang
    arr := new([5]int)
    i := interface{}(arr)
    arr1, ok := i.(*[5]int)
    fmt.Println(arr1, ok)
```